# Android File sharing via Bluetooth

Tags: android

I have an requirement to list all available device on bluetooth and share any file from android device to selected device. I tried to use the below code

```
 private void sharefile(String deviceAddress,String filePath){
        File f =  new File(filePath);
        BluetoothAdapter objBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
                        .getDefaultAdapter();

                BluetoothDevice device = objBluetoothAdapter
                        .getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
                Log.v("Device", "" + device.getName());

                final UUID uuid = UUID
                        .fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.length()];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                    bis.read(buffer, 0, (int) f.length());

                    BluetoothSocket socket = device
                            .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);

                    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
                    socket.close();   
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }
```

While executing the above code shows an **Transport endpoint not connected** message on Logcat.

**06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812): java.io.IOException: Transport endpoint is not connected
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.writeNative(Native Method)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.write(BluetoothSocket.java:346)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothOutputStream.write(BluetoothOutputStream.java:85)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at com.cit.bt.ShareMessageActivity.connectDevice(ShareMessageActivity.java:138)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at com.cit.bt.ShareMessageActivity.shareFile(ShareMessageActivity.java:83)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at com.cit.bt.ShareMessageActivity.onListItemClick(ShareMessageActivity.java:73)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3736)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1974)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-11 18:26:49.960: W/System.err(9812):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**

and also tried to use below alternative code to connect the device,it connect the device but failed to transfer the file.

```
BluetoothDevice hxm = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                .getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
        Method m;

            m = hxm.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                    new Class[] { int.class });
            BluetoothSocket socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(hxm,
                    Integer.valueOf(1));
            socket.connect();
```

I have provided required permission in android manifest too, but it's failed to connect.
Anyone help me to fix this problem.

Can you anyone provide me the logic behind the Bluetooth File Transfer from Android market.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That Bluetooth HMX device wouldn't happen to be a heart rate monitor by any chance?
Either way we have posted a nice example (stemming from the Google Bluetooth Chat example). It's a little more stripped down than they example and hopefully you'll find it helpful.

http://ww2.cs.fsu.edu/~sposaro/mobile/resources/BeatConnect.zip

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I don't want the app to be installed on both devices like client-server module. can you provide me the sample to detect the nearby bluetooth device and share file. without client-server module. As one like Bluetooth file transfer from Android market.

Comment: have you paired the bluetooth device with the android device?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry I do not remember off hand how everything happened. I know that the code I provided connects with a BlueTooth HeartRate monitor device.